# Container restricts individual margins wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Currently im making a wordpress page, and i want to add these small author cards (pic related), which i can't seem to align side by side.

i figured that the margin is what restricts me from doing so.

The boxes are composed of shortcode. and i made my own div in my stylesheet to resize the width to 50%. However these author boxes are within a container, that sets a fixed margin, so if i for example try to float the boxes respectively left and right, they still align on top of each other.

Furthermore i tried adding individual div tags to my boxes, in order to css my way out of it, however still no luck.

Is there a way in which i can override the original margin?

[image]

Comment: You have the site/page where you are facing the issue is live?

Comment: http://bkrt.dk/wp/index.php/kontakt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this CSS --

```
.author-shortcodes {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This will make those 2 boxes to stay next to each other. If applying this CSS does not really override, use 'display:inline-block !important;' instead.

Comment: you are simply a genious. thank you! i've spend 2 hours on this.

Comment: by the way. as you can see on my page now, i've added 4, however i need 6. I dont seem to be able to add the last two.

Comment: Well my bad, chrome didnt recognize that i updated the page the 2'nd time :) Thank you again